# Python Templates - Include/With - Passing parameters

Tags: python, html, django

So according to the Django docs, in python we can pass a parameter from one template to another. 
So at present I have a main html template (home.html) which my python program renders. It passes a username parameter as 'un'.

To print this parameter in the home.html I do:

```
{% if user_info %} {{ un }} {% endif %} //this works and prints the username
```

Now I have another template that is included within the main.html. 
It is called user.html. I have included it as below wit using the 'with' statement to pass the parameter

```
{% include 'sub_pages/user.html' with un=un %}
```

The error I get:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'with'
```

Why is this happening? Also when and if the parameter does pass to the sub template do I print it in the same way as I'am printing on the main.html?

Comment: Show the full `main.html` file. It seems like another templatetag is not properly closed!

Comment: All the template tags are closed. Everything works as expected if I remove "with un=un"

Comment: To answer you sub-question, yes, you print it in the same way as inside `main.html` (i.e `{{ un }}`). Now, for the main question, what version of Django are you using? Show more HTML code in order to help you!